# fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel

I have tried to recompile the kernel with `make` command for config but this error occured:

```
scripts/extract-cert.c:21:10: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/bio.h>
```

So then a i have tried install `libssl-dev`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1b-1ubuntu2) but 1.1.1b-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone tell me how can i fix my dependecies? And why do I have them broken?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/630439/libssl-dev-version-dependency-conflict-with-installed-libssl1-0-0. And [ubuntu.se] is a better place for questions about `apt` package manager and packages it manages.

Answer (score 20):

Try to install `aptitude` and use this tool for downgrading of libssl-dev.

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

After this step use aptitude to downgrade your to 1.1.1b-1ubuntu2 from 1.1.1b-1ubuntu2.1

```
$ sudo aptitude install libssl-dev
```

Choose carefully the option. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

you need to install some required packages：

```
sudo apt-get install make build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

Comment: These are for compiling linux kernel